# Exporting photos from Survey123 GDB file with custom filenames?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, arcgis-survey123

I have a Survey123 Survey that I've been using to collect data with multiple pictures on each datapoint.

Each datapoint has a barcode to correspond with a physical sample taken from each point. I would like to export the photos out of the survey data, which I have done by creating a script in ArcMap, using the code below from this [article](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011912):

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import da
import os

inTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
fileLocation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

with da.SearchCursor(inTable, ['DATA', 'ATT_NAME', 'ATTACHMENTID']) as cursor:
    for item in cursor:
        attachment = item[0]
        filename = 'ATT' + str(item[1])
        open(fileLocation + os.sep + filename, 'wb').write(attachment.tobytes())
        del item
        del filename
        del attachment
```

However this does not allow me to rename the file using the barcode that is associated with that datapoint. So when the photos are exported, they are no longer associated with the relevant data.

I would like to tell the SearchCursor function to also take the `sample_id` field from the data table and add that to the filename. When I add the sample_id to the array inside the SearchCursor function like this:

`with da.SearchCursor(inTable, ['DATA', 'ATT_NAME', 'ATTACHMENTID', 'sample_id']) as cursor`

I get the following error: `RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist.`

I would like help in calling the `sample_id` field into the function properly so it can be added to the filename variable.

Comment: Are you sure your table has the `sample_id` field and that is being spelled correctly (*e.g.* could be `SAMPLE_ID` instead)?

Comment: I don't think the ```sample_id``` is in the table. From what I could find it sounds like the photos are part of a different layer, and I don't know how to call that in either. And I tried multiple variations for the naming, hoping that would be the issue.

Comment: If the field is not part of the table you won't be able to access it using a cursor. Have you already identified the other table? Any chance you can join both tables to get all the information?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by identify the other table. I assume it's the table with the metadata in it, which I have downloaded as a csv. However I don't know how to find that within ArcMap other than opening the attribute table. I bet joining would work but I don't know how to do that either. Day 1 here in ArcMap

Comment: Refer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238408/joining-csv-with-shapefile-in-arcgis-desktop) or [this other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75885/joining-shapefile-table-with-csv) for information about joining a csv with a shapefile in ArcMap. After you have joined both tables it should be rather simple to accomplish what you are trying to do because you will be able to access the field using `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()`.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo, I'll give that a whirl. Not sure what will change since the original export was a .gdb file, which is what the other articles are suggesting I make.

Comment: Can you list the tables and feature classes that are in the GDB?

Comment: It has been a while since I looked at a Table with Attachments from Survey123, but I know with Collector for ArcGIS the attachments were stored in a table linked to the main feature in the GDB. Within the table of attachments there was a field called "REL_GUID" or something similar that referred to the GUI in the main feature set that particular attachment was linked to. It is possible to use this "REL_GUID" to link back to the main feature class and pull the name / barcode from the associated feature.

Comment: I can't remember the names off the top of my head and I'm not in front of the computer right now. I'll check back tomorrow. Would I have to export to excel and run a vlookup or something in order to reference the GUID with the other data?

Comment: @SonofaBeach The tables are Form_2__ATTACH and GDB_ServiceItems. Then there is an icon with three dots in it, called Form_2. And the fourth item is and icon with two little boxes with arrows pointing from one to the other called Form_2__ATTACHREL. Maybe I should reference that last one as it might already be a joined layer?

Comment: I tried running the script with Form_2__ATTACHREL layer, but that produced an error: ```RuntimeError: cannot open 'C:local_filepath\Form_2__ATTACHREL'```

Answer (score 3):

If your survey submits data to a feature class called 'Form_2' (a common default name), and the survey includes image questions (photos, signatures, etc), then...

There will be a table of related images called 'Form_2_ATTACH'.  This table will have a GUID field called "REL_GLOBALID". This contains the GUID (global ID) of the survey record that the image belongs with.  You can use this to join an image with it's related survey data and then you can get all the information you need.

Try something like this (untested!):

```
import arcpy, os

pathToGDB = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
fileLocation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

surveyFC = os.path.join(pathToGDB, "Form_2")
imageTable = os.path.join(pathToGDB, "Form_2__ATTACH")
imageSurveyView = "imageSurveyView"  #  Using a variable instead of a string makes typo errors less likely

arcpy.MakeTableView_management (imageTable, imageSurveyView)
arcpy.AddJoin_management (imageSurveyView, "REL_GLOBALID", surveyFC, "GlobalID", "KEEP_ALL")

#  print [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(imageSurveyView)]

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(imageSurveyView, ['Form_2__ATTACH.DATA', 'Form_2__ATTACH.ATT_NAME', 'Form_2__ATTACH.ATTACHMENTID', 'Form_2.sample_id']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        attachment = item[0]
        filename = 'ATT_{}_{}_{}'.format(row[1], row[2], row[3])
        with open(os.path.join(fileLocation, filename), 'wb') as f:
            f.write(attachment.tobytes())
```

(Note the change to the first parameter - this is the GDB, not the table.  You may want to include both as separate parameters.  I've hard-coded the table name in the code.)

This will join the image table to the survey feature class, and then the `SearchCursor` can iterate over the rows of the table view instead of the table itself.  You can now use fields from both the photos table and the form table in the `SearchCursor` fields, including your `sample_id` field.

NB:  You may need to fully qualify your fields in the `SearchCursor` to include the table name, because the join means there are multiple tables behind this table view.  Eg, use `Form_2__ATTACH.ATT_NAME` instead of `ATT_NAME` and `Form_2.sample_id` instead of `sample_id`.

The above code would include the `ATT_NAME`, the `ATTACHEMENTID` and the `sample_id` in the filename.  But it's up to you which of these items you actually want to include (but if you include ONLY the sample_id, you may have several photo files that would end up with the same name and overwrite each other).

(Note that there will also be a 'Form_2__ATTACHREL' which is what ESRI call a relationship class.  You can ignore this for these purposes, as you can do your join in code and use that instead.  The relationship class does not contain any data (usually). It just defines the relationship between the form data feature class and the images table, including which fields are used as the key for joining the two.  It is used by ArcMap or ArcGIS Online to be able to navigate from a parent record to a child record easily.)

Answer (score 1):

I have found some code I was using a Python Toolbox, it was setup for use with Collector for ArcGIS, but I think the same rules will apply to the output from Survey123. I cannot take credit for this code, it is a mix and match of scripts and ideas from this site over the years. I hope it is condensed and applicable to your application.

```
def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        origTable = parameters[0].ValueAsText #Input Featureclass
               attachTable = parameter

    s[1].ValueAsText # if no attachTable given, append __ATTACH to origTable
           nameField = parameters[3].ValueAsText  # appropriate name field in origTable
           fileLocation = parameters[2].ValueAsText #Output Folder

           origFieldsList = ["GlobalID", "OBJECTID", nameField] # GlobalID for linking, OBJECTID for renaming, nameField for renaming

        # Use list comprehension to build a dictionary from a da SearchCursor
           valueDict = {r[0]:(r[1:]) for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(origTable, origFieldsList)}


           count = 1
           with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(attachTable, ['DATA', 'ATT_NAME', 'ATTACHMENTID', 'REL_GLOBALID']) as cursor:
            for item in cursor:
                attachment = item[0] # attachment data


                filenum = "ATT" + str(item[2]) + "_"

                filename = filenum + str(item[1])  # this will be the filename if linking fails

            # store the Join value of the row being updated in a keyValue variable
                keyValue = item[3] # REL_GLOBALID
            # verify that the keyValue is in the Dictionary
                if keyValue in valueDict:
                # transfer the values stored under the keyValue from the dictionary to the updated fields.
                    obID = valueDict[keyValue][0]

                # remove invalid filename characters, replace spaces and periods, limit length
                    check = str(valueDict[keyValue][1])

                    if check == 'None':  #Check for Null Values
                        namefield = "NoValue"
                    else:
                        namefield = re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '_', valueDict[keyValue][1])[:18]



                # Create a unique filename  ObjectID_AttachmentID_namefield.ext
                    ext = filename.rsplit('.', 1)[-1] # keep extension of original file
                    filename = "{}_{}_{}.{}".format(namefield,"OID" + str(obID),"ATTID" +str(item[2]),ext)

                arcpy.AddMessage( "Writing: {}{}{}".format(fileLocation, os.sep, filename))
                arcpy.AddMessage ("Processing: " + str(count))
                count = count +1

                open(fileLocation + os.sep + filename, 'wb').write(attachment.tobytes())
                del item
                del filenum
                del filename
                del attachment
            del count
    return
```

There are 4 parameters, in order they are:

1. origTable - the input feature class - the point feature from your
   survey
2. AttachTable - This is the table containing the attachments, it is
   usually the original table name with "__ATTACH" on the end.
3. nameField - appropriate name field in origTable - the name you want
   to add to the attachment exported
4. fileLocation - a folder path

You will need to code these into your script.
The script then looks over the REL_GLOBAL ID in the Attachment Table and finds the appropriate GLOBAL ID in the main table and looks for the field you specified as an input, and then assigns that name to the attachment name. If there are more than one attachments per point, it adds a number to the end.