# Batch Exporting Survey123 GDB Photos with custom filenames

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, arcgis-survey123

I'm trying to export photos from Survey 123 with custom filenames by joining fields in another feature class.

I worked through ESRI's documentation "[How To: Batch export attachments from a feature class in ArcMap"](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011912) and got that working. Then I tried to follow the answers on an [identical question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329748/exporting-photos-from-survey123-gdb-file-with-custom-filenames) asked here on StackExchange to use custom filenames.

After sitting with the top answer for a few hours I decided a simpler route. Instead, I decided to just do a join myself in ArcMap and exported it out as a table. Even still, I haven't been able to get it up and running. I just want to change ESRI's script to use a name based on a field that I joined to the table:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import da
import os

inTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
fileLocation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

with da.SearchCursor(inTable, ['OBJECTID_1', 'DATA', 'ATT_NAME', 'field_site_number']) as cursor:
    for item in cursor:
        attachment = item[1]
        filenum = str(item[0])
        filename = str(item[3]) + " " + str(item[2])
        open(fileLocation + os.sep + filename, 'wb').write(attachment.tobytes())
        del item
        del filenum
        del filename
        del attachment
```

But I keep getting an AttributeError that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\userDesktop\ExportAttachments.py", line 13, in <module>
    open(fileLocation + os.sep + filename, 'wb').write(attachment.tobytes())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tobytes'
```

The `'DATA'` field in the `attachments` variable is just populated as Blob. I have no idea why it's prompting this error or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This error implies `attachment` is `None` (NULL) for a least one record.

This in turn implies that `attachment = item[1]` is assigning `None` (NoneType).  Which implies that the `'DATA'` field has a NULL value (for at least one record).

Is it possible that no photo was included for one (or more) of the surveys?

If so, your script needs to cater for this possibility.  Eg:

```
...
...
with da.SearchCursor(inTable, ['OBJECTID_1', 'DATA', 'ATT_NAME', 'field_site_number']) as cursor:
    for item in cursor:
        if item[1] is None:
            continue  #  Skip this iteration of the for loop
        attachment = item[1]
        ...
        ...
```

In this case, if `'DATA'` is `None` (NULL), then the rest of this iteration of the `for` loop would be skipped and continue with the next iteration of the `for` loop.  You may want to handle it differently, but one way or another you have to test for `None` and do something about it.

If you are confident that there are no records with NULL `DATA`, then you could add a `print` statement to verify what data you are getting.  Eg,

```
...
...
with da.SearchCursor(inTable, ['OBJECTID_1', 'DATA', 'ATT_NAME', 'field_site_number']) as cursor:
    for item in cursor:
        print("DATA:  {}".format(item[1]))
        if item[1] is None:
            continue  #  Skip this iteration of the for loop
        attachment = item[1]
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: Although this solution is valid. I did not get any output after running the script. Handling the null values by printing them is also giving me zero output. 

However, it appears that the SearchCursor function can't read the collumns in my joined table. I keep getting an error that says `RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist.`

Comment: Sounds like the print statement is never reached at all.  You need to check your column names.  If it is a joined table, the columns will need to be fully qualified, not just the base names.  Eg, “someTable.DATA”.  You can use arcpy.ListFields() to get all the fully qualified field names and then print them.

Comment: ...eg,before your `with.da.SearchCursor`, do this:  `print [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(inTable)]`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me.

I could never get `da.SearchCursor` to recognize joined fields even when specifying the joined name listed in the "Field Name" properties within the Attachment Table.(eg. "survey.field_site")

Using ArcGIS Pro v.2.5 I was able to create a new field in the Attachment Table that allowed me to to generate values based on a joined field. Initially, I tried doing the same thing in ArcMAP v.10.7.1 but for some reason ArcMap would not allow me to add a new field to a table with a join.

Only after I created the new field within my attachment table based on a joined field was I able to use `da.SearchCursor` to customize my file names.

Final script:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import da
import os

inTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
fileLocation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

with da.SearchCursor(inTable, ['DATA', 'ATT_NAME', 'ATTACHMENTID', 'SITE']) as cursor:
    for item in cursor:
        attachment = item[0]
        filenum = "ATT" + str(item[2]) + "_"
        filename = str(item[3]) + "_" + filenum + str(item[1])
        open(fileLocation + os.sep + filename, 'wb').write(attachment.tobytes())
        del item
        del filenum
        del filename
        del attachment
```